# Dimension of coordinate datapoints

Tags: carto, coordinates

How can I see in Carto the density of data points geolocalized if some of them are located in the same coordinates? In an example:

If I have 5 coordinates as follows:

```
50.64815,12.96872     
48.65920,8.94052    
48.65920,8.94052   
48.65920,8.94052   
48.65920,8.94052
```

In Carto I will be able to see 2 datapoints (because four coordinates are the same). However, the dimension of these 2 datapoints are displayed with exactly the same dimension.

I'd expect to see a map showing these 2 datapoints but one 4 times bigger than the other.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a query, group by coordinates and count data points.

```
select count (*), x, y from table group by x, y
```

Or use directly the geometry column

```
select count (*), the_geom from table group by then geometry
```

If you want the number of points as 3rd dimension in your coordinate query like this

```
Select st_makepoint (x, y, count (*)) from table group by x, y
```

To transform to Web mecator add another function

```
Select st_transform (st_makepoint (x, y, count (*)),3857) from table group by x, y
```

Make sure the column names match your table.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to make a bubble map (or graduated symbols map) based on the number of points per location:

1-First, import your file as a csv, xlsx or [another supported format](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/importing-geospatial-data#supported-geospatial-data-formats) into CARTO. I recommend naming your coordiantes columns like `lat`/`latitude` and `long`/`longitude`. In doing so, the importer will recognize them and will geocode them.
2-Secondly, apply a query similar as the one @Thomas suggested:

```
SELECT
  min(cartodb_id) as cartodb_id,
  the_geom,
  the_geom_webmercator,
  count(*) as number_points
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  2,3
```

Or you can use `Find centroids from geometries` as explained in the 2nd part of [this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/find-centroid-from-geometries), selecting `the_geom` as category.
 
3-Third, you can create a map from the query ("on the fly") or create a new dataset from it (and create a map afterwards).
4-In BUILDER, go to STYLE and style the `marker-width` by value (as explained [in this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-by-value)), selecting `number_points`.